# HTML based Email sending not working in Django with SMTP

Tags: python, django, email

This is what I ran in the django python shell

```
    from django.core.mail import EmailMessage
    email = EmailMessage('Hello', 'Test<br>break', 'sender@mysite.com',['receiver@gmail.com'])
    email.content_subtype = "html"
    email.send()
```

`email.send()` returned `1` in python shell, When I checked my sender email I have not received any mail
I am not sure what that `1` means

Here is my `settings.py` file mail settings

```
EMAIL_HOST = 'smtp.zoho.com'
EMAIL_HOST_USER = 'sender@mysite.com'
EMAIL_HOST_PASSWORD = 'mypass'
EMAIL_PORT = 587
EMAIL_USE_TLS = True

EMAIL_BACKEND = 'django.core.mail.backends.smtp.EmailBackend'
```

Comment: `send()` returns the number of messages successfully sent, so your messages are being accepted by the SMTP server. Check that they aren't going to spam or something.

Comment: yes, it went to SPAM folder, do you know How to make it to go to main Inbox

Comment: There could be any number of reasons why it's going to spam - read Google's [bulk sender guidelines](https://support.google.com/mail/answer/81126) for how you can improve the chances that it doesn't.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So `email.send()` returned `1` meanings it's a successful mail.

The mail went to Spam box in Gmail

When I wrote actual content that I want to send it came to my inbox.